# Display header size of collectionView based on a collection view dynamic content inside of that header not working

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionView(1) on which I am setting up a header. This header has inside another collectionView(2). Now I am trying to set the headerSize in referenceSizeForHeaderInSection based on the size of the collectionView(2) in the header. I am basically stuck, don't know where to go from here, I tried everything. I was able to get the header height with:

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

but only in the collectionView(2) setting up a public variable. Trying to get the public var it will not work in collectionView(1) referenceSizeForHeaderInSection (only if I use a DispatchQueue which cannot get a return value for the header). Probably I am doing something wrong. Need help, another direction, anything it's appreciated.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "VideoHeader", for: indexPath)
    header.removeFromSuperview()
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    headerAdvertCollection.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    header.addSubview(headerAdvertCollection.collectionView)
    headerAdvertCollection.collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    headerAdvertCollection.collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    headerAdvertCollection.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    headerAdvertCollection.collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

    headerAdvertCollection.setupCollectionView()

    return header
}

//MARK: Collection View Header Height
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    let advertisingView : CGFloat = 450
    let height : CGFloat = advertisingView

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 10, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have collectionView1 and collectionView2, you can access one of them in the delegate/datasource methods simply by doing an if check.

For example, in referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

   if collectionView == collectionView1{
     let advertisingView : CGFloat = 450
     let height : CGFloat = advertisingView

     //supposing you want to use collectionView2
     return CGSize(width: collectionView2.frame.width - 10, height: height)
   }else{
     // HERE YOU CAN RETURN A VALUE FOR collectionView2
   }
```

}

> ***NOTE:*** to use collectionView1 and collectionView2, you need to link the outlets

Comment: Hi Andrew. The thing is if you try to get a value from collectionView2 which is in the header of collectionView1 that value will be 0. The header of collectionView1 is loading the collectionView2 which means that it's loading before I can find out the height, so I won't be able to set it up.

Comment: Then you can save the value into a class variable, then reload the collection view 2 with that value

Comment: I would still have a problem with the first thing the user see. In this case a header disproportionate or with value 0 no header at all until another reload :).